# How to apply filter in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

In JMeter, I have recorded a script in HTTP test script recorder and generated a test script. I'm passing 10 users into the thread group.

In the view result tree, I get the result for the 10 users, but I want to check the response time for each user.

[image]

How can I identify the individual user response times?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this as follows:

1. Add [__threadNum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) as a prefix (or postfix) for all [HTTP Request samplers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) like:

   ```
   HTTP Request User: ${__threadNum}
   ```

   This way JMeter will append current virtual user number to sampler name (label)

   [image: JMeter Append User ID to sampler]
2. Once done you will be able to use [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/) to filter the results to only that user you are particularly interested in.

   Filter results tool can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

   [image: JMeter Plugins Manager Filter Results Tool]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "[View Results in Table](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_in_Table)" listener. Here, you can select all rows (Ctrl+A) and then copy/paste all the data into an excel sheet. Now, you need to [filter](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/filter-data-in-a-range-or-table-01832226-31b5-4568-8806-38c37dcc180e) by column "Thread Name". The number in Thread Group value (i.e. 1-2) represents the sent request for the corresponding "virtual user". After the filter is applied, you can sort all records and the result will be requests per user with all statistic data available.

[image]

EDIT:
A better solution would be to use [Simple Data Writer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) and add it to your test group. I am not sure how it's configured by default but you can select all necessary data you want to extract from the "Configure" button. In my case I created a .csv file and when I open it, I can sort the requests by user (column threadName). Here's a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: While this is a valid answer, could you please expand on it to explain how the results in table listener will display individual user response times?